How to drag multi selected rows in NatTable correctly?
In the NatTable,I use ctrl+click to choose multi rows.Then the mouse up.Then I want to drag them,but the drag need to press and move.If I don't press ctrl,the row I press is the only row I can drag.If I press ctrl and drag,the result is loose the row which I press last.
For example,there are four rows,A,B,C and D.I selected A B C,then I drag from A to D with ctrl,only B C move,and A is not selected because of the click when drag.
I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.
All functions in the DragSourceEvent and DropSourceEvent have been tried,but I can't solute the question.
I think the focus of this question is the click target before drag.In other words,the drag action has two part,the first is mousedown and the second is move.But when mouse down,the click action is found first.

This would normally work as intended, i.e. for a single item click + drag would actually use the click event first to select the item and then initiate the drag. When you select multiple items you'd either have to use special handling, i.e. drag when selecting the last item, or suppress deselecting items upon a click when CTRL is pressed.

Please specify your use case in more detail. Do you want to perform multi row dragging inside nattable or do you want to drag items out to another control? Do you select rows via row header or do you have custom bindings to select rows in the body region?

I wish to correct your English. You wrote (in your question): I can't solute the question. If you are referring to the verb form of the word solution, then it is solve, so you should write: I can't solve the question.

The first thing that needs to be changed is the default selection binding for single clicks. You need to avoid that the mouse down action triggers a selection. This can be done for example with this snippet
selectionLayer.addConfiguration(new AbstractUiBindingConfiguration() {

    @Override
    public void configureUiBindings(UiBindingRegistry uiBindingRegistry) {
        uiBindingRegistry.registerFirstMouseDownBinding(
                MouseEventMatcher.rowHeaderLeftClick(SWT.NONE),
                new ViewportSelectRowAction(false, false) {
                    @Override
                    public void run(NatTable natTable, MouseEvent event) {
                        // get the row position in the SelectionLayer on
                        // which the click was performed
                        int rowPosition = LayerUtil.convertRowPosition(natTable,
                                natTable.getRowPositionByY(event.y), selectionLayer);
                        // only perform a selection if the row is not
                        // selected yet
                        // this is to avoid changing an existing
                        // selection of multiple rows to a single
                        // selection
                        if (!selectionLayer.isRowPositionFullySelected(rowPosition)) {
                            super.run(natTable, event);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
});

The second thing that needs to be changed depends on the use case. If you want to reorder multiple rows inside a NatTable, you need to change the default reorder bindings, because multi row reordering in NatTable is not enabled by default. You need to change the default drag mode to make this work. The default RowReorderDragMode only takes the row where the mouse down is performed and drags that single position to the target position. This needs to be changed so that all selected rows are taken and moved. The reason for the default single row reorder behavior, is the dependency to the SelectionLayer that would be needed in the RowReorderLayer, which needs to be avoided in the default setup.
There is an example in the NatTable Examples that shows the code that is needed for such a change.
StructuralRowReorderWithoutRowHeaderExample
Note that reordering inside a NatTable has nothing to do with the SWT drag & drop support. To add that you need to implement for example a DragSourceListener that knows the SelectionLayer and is able to get the selected rows from there.
There is also an example for Drag & Drop Support in the NatTable Examples. That example currently only supports single selection. But if you enable multi selection in the RowSelectionModel, change the selection binding to avoid selection on single click (see above, just for the bodyLeftClick and not the rowHeaderLeftClick, and update the DragAndDropSupport to handle multiple row objects, it should work.
DragAndDropExample
